# Using regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check whether information entered are 3 character long, first one should be `0-9` second `A-Z` and third `0-9` again.

I have written pattern as below:

```
var pattern = `'^[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z]$'`;
var valid = str.match(pattern);
```

I got confused with usage of regex for selecting, matching and replacing.

- In this case, does`[A-Z]` check only one character or whole string ?
- Does `+` separate(split?) out characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `+` matches one or more. You want exactly one

2) declare your pattern as a REGEX literal, inside forward slashes

With these two points in mind, your pattern should be

```
/^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]$/
```

Note also you can make the pattern slightly shorter by replacing `[0-9]` with the `\d` shortcut (matches any numerical character).

3) Optionally, add the case-insensitive `i` flag after the final trailing slash if you want to allow either case.

4) If you want to merely *test* a string matches a pattern, rather than retrieve a match from it, use `test()`, not `match()` - it's more efficient.

```
var valid = pattern.test(str); //true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` means one or more characters so a possible String would be ABCD1234EF or A3B, invalid is 3B or A 6B

Comment: the `+` symbol without being highlighted as code creates a list !

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you need :

```
^[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$
```

> In this case, does[A-Z] check only one character or whole string ?

It's just check 1 char but a char can be many times in a string..

you should add ^ and $ in order to match the whole string like I did.

> Does + separate(split?) out characters?
>   no.

`+` sign just shows that a chars can repeat 1+ times.

Answer (score 0):

"+" means one or more. In your case you should use exact quantity match:

```
/^\w{1}\d{1}\w{1}$/
```